# how to access variable from config file in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have one file inside config folder lets say: `file1`

```
File Location:
    config/
    ---file1.php
```

I have following code in my file: `file1.php`

```
return [
 'MASTER_KEY' => ['SUB_KEY1' => 'SOME_VALUE', 'SUB_KEY2' => 'SOME_VALUE', 'SUB_KEY3' => 'SOME_VALUE'],
];
```

How to access the value from `MASTER_KEY` of particular `SUB_KEY`?

Answer (score 17):

Assuming for `SUB_KEY2`, Try -

```
config('file1.MASTER_KEY.SUB_KEY2')
```

[Guide](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/ho-to-access-config-variables-in-laravel-5)

Comment: I appreciate your feedback but i want to access SUBKEY value

Comment: Which `SUBKEY` value?

Answer (score 6):

use

```
config('file1.keyname');
```

if you have made any changes in config file then it might not work . so after changes in config file you have to run the following two commands .

```
php artisan config:cache

php artisan config:clear
```

Comment: your comment is life saver

Answer (score 5):

In order to access that value you have 2 choices which are the same at the end:

**first one:** which `use Config` refers to the config facade.

```
use Config;

$myValue = Config::get('file1.MASTER_KEY.SUB_KEY1');
enter code here
```

**second one:** using `config()` helper function which uses `Config` facade and its only an alternative and easy way to use `Config` facade.

```
$myValue = config('file1.MASTER_KEY.SUB_KEY1');
```

Answer (score 3):

Make a use Config; in your controller.
In config/file1.php

```
<?php return [
    'ADMIN_NAME' => 'administrator',
    'EMP_IMG_PATH' => '../uploads/profile/original',
    'EMP_DOC_PATH' => '../uploads/profile/documents', ];
```

In controller

```
use Config;
$variable= Config::get('file1.EMP_DOC_PATH');
```

By this way you can get the variables value from config.
I think this will make something good.